# NancyFX: Routes with query string parameters always returns a 404 NotFound

Tags: .net, query-string, nancy

I have a simple Nancy module. I want to pass in query string (q-s) parameters to the handler. If I do not have any q-s params everything is fine. As soon as I add a param then I get a 404 status code returned.

**NancyModule**

```
public class SimpleModule : NancyModule
{
    public SimpleModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = parameters => HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
}
```

**Unit Test - Passes**

```
[Fact]
public void SimpleModule__Should_return_statusOK_when_passing_query_params()
{
    const string uri = "/";
    var response = Fake.Browser().Get(uri, with => with.HttpRequest());
    response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

**Unit Test - Fails**

```
[Fact]
public void SimpleModule__Should_return_statusOK_when_passing_query_params()
{
    const string uri = "/?id=1";
    var response = Fake.Browser().Get(uri, with => with.HttpRequest());
    response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't pass in the query on the url, instead use the .Query method on the browser context

```
var result = browser.Get("/", with => {
    with.Query("key", "value");
});
```

Comment: I can't say this is very SDHP.

Comment: @tom.dietrich this qas posted over a year ago and since then the behavior has changed so that it works

Comment: That didn't appear to be the case when I ran into this same thing last week.

Comment: @tom.dietrich which of the following cases where you attempting? https://gist.github.com/thecodejunkie/204297b492e1ab5b3e2f all these tests pass. If you have an issue, please raise it on our GitHub repo along with steps to reproduce and we'll take a look

Comment: Should_return_querystring_parameter_when_passed_in_with_path is failing.  It only works when I pass in the full URL such as http://localhost/foo?bar=123
But not with /foo?bar=123

Comment: I can confirm that bug is still present, using Nancy.Testing 1.4.1.0

Comment: @TheCodeJunkie if i have multiple query parameter how would i pass ?