# Nancy Routes resulting in 404

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-404, nancy

I inherited a WCF project containing some badly constructed routes (which work) that I need to migrate into a new NancyFx project. I need to be able to define routes in my Nancy app that respond to the same GET requests. I cannot change the routes for the time being.

In the WCF project, a GET request to ...

```
http://localhost:12345/webapi/GetUsers?UserId=567&Language=en
```

matches this UriTemplate:

```
UriTemplate = "GetUsers?UserId={userId}&Language={language}
```

I was hoping this would be the equivalent in Nancy

```
Get["/GetUsers?UserId={userId}&Language={language}"] = p => { ... }
```

but the same GET request results in a 404.

Is there a way to structure my Nancy route to respond to this GET request? If not, any  work-arounds?

I know this is horrible but its temporary until I can schedule time with our UI team to rewrite the front-end to call proper rest-full URLs.

Comment: I call duplicate, answer for you is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718763/nancyfx-routes-with-query-string-parameters-always-returns-a-404-notfound

Comment: @triazotan no, it is not he same issue

Comment: Skimming fail, I stand corrected ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

John,

Your route would be `/GetUsers` (how are you handling the `/webapi` part by the way? Is that the base url of your application or are you setting up a module path?) and you would read the query-string using the `Request.Query` member.

The Query property returns a `DynamicDictionary` which enables you to access the values as either properties `Request.Query.UserId` or as a dictionary `Request.Query["UserId"]`

You cannot make the query-string part of pattern that needs to be matched in order for the routes to be invoked. What you can do, if you really want to, is to use the route condition, which is the second parameter on the route declaration. This gives you control over a predicate which determines if the route is OK to be used or not. So you could do something like this

```
Get["/GetUsers", ctx => ctx.Request.Query.UserId.HasValue && ctx.Request.Query.Language.HasValue] = p {... }
```

You could then refactor it all to an extension method, on NancyContext, that makes it a bit tidier

```
Get["/GetUsers", ctx => ctx.HasQueryValues("UserId", "Language")] = p {... }
```

and make the extension something like

```
public static bool HasQueryValues(this NancyContext context, params string[] values)
{
   return values.All(x => context.Request.Query[x].HasValue);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, this solves it. I was stuck thinking that I needed to match the querystring part because we have overloads. (The `/webapi` part is my base url, btw).

Answer (score 5):

Following on from @TheCodeJunkie's answer, I got somewhat overexcited by his idea of extending the `NancyContext` to provide route conditions that pre-check the `Query` values to ensure the Request is valid. I have further extended my `NancyContext` to provide the same pre-checks for the `Form` values, `Header` collection and even the `Files` collection, like so:

```
public static bool HasQuery(this NancyContext context, params string[] values)
{
    var query = context.Request.Query;
    return values.All(value => query[value].HasValue);
}

public static bool HasForm(this NancyContext context, params string[] values)
{
    var form = context.Request.Form;
    return values.All(value => form[value].HasValue);
}

public static bool HasHeader(this NancyContext context, params string[] values)
{
    var headers = context.Request.Headers;
    return values.All(value => !headers[value].FirstOrDefault().IsEmpty());
}

public static bool HasFile(this NancyContext context, params string[] values)
{
    var files = context.Request.Files;
    return values.All(value => files.Any(file => file.Key == value));
}
```

This has allowed me to remove the ceremonial code that was validating the Query and Form values (when I remembered to do this, which wasn't every time as it turned out). So you get cleaner code that is easier to read and easier to remember to do the checks in the first place, for example:

**Before**

```
Post["/"]=_=>
{
    var form = Request.Form;
    if (
        !form.username.HasValue ||
        !form.password.HasValue ||
        !form.email.HasValue ||
        !form.claim.HasValue)
    {
        return HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity;
    }
    //process form values with confidence
}
```

**After**

```
Post["/", ctx => ctx.HasForm("username", "password", "email", "claim")]=_=>
{
    //process form values with confidence   
};
```